# Sequencing results in function PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am setting a function for a trigger triggered when I insert in tableA, which I would first to create an entry in tableB, and then create some other entries in tableC in which there is a foreign key related to tableB. But I get an error since it tries insert into tableC a value in the foreign key field which doesn't exists in the tableB as long as the function didn't finish to run.

Is there a way that inside a function, put some sort of return inside my function but which would not exit the function and then execute the rest of it ? Something which would look like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger1() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
insert into tableB values (new.value);
RETURN NEW;
insert into tableC (id, fkey) values (new.something, new.value);
RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried to separate the function in two different triggers, using the alphabetical order to order the execution, but without success, maybe because they are both run BEFORE...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Declare the foreign key in tableC as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`.

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html)

> DEFERRABLE NOT DEFERRABLE
>
> This controls whether the constraint can be deferred. A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after every
>   command. Checking of constraints that are deferrable can be postponed
>   until the end of the transaction (using the SET CONSTRAINTS command).
>   NOT DEFERRABLE is the default. Currently, only UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY,
>   EXCLUDE, and REFERENCES (foreign key) constraints accept this clause.
>   NOT NULL and CHECK constraints are not deferrable.

Btw. the first `RETURN NEW;` in the function body makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks. I have trouble understanding how this work though. What is happening if I defer the foreign key and if the CONSTRAINT is not being respected? Will it raise an error? At the end of the transaction so it will "remember" the whole transaction and cancel it?

Comment: Yes, on a constraint failure an error will be raised and the transaction will rollback. However you do not have to use an explicite transaction. If you have no outer transaction then the trigger function is a single transaction itself. Generally it works as you would expect, without the need of changing anything in a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's impossible to have two `RETURN` statements in same flow of a function.

About your problem, there are many ways to achieve this. One of those is using a `DEFERRABLE TRIGGER` (an special type of trigger evaluated at end of transaction). Something like:

```
--Trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger1() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "tableB" VALUES (new.value);
    INSERT INTO "tableC" (id, fkey) VALUES (new.something, new.value);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--Trigger raised at end of transaction. Take a look on 'CONSTRAINT' and 'INITIALLY DEFERRED' clauses.
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER deferred_trigger_1
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON "tableA"
  INITIALLY DEFERRED  
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger1();
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Thank you. However I cannot find how these DEFERRABLE TRIGGER works. Could you provide me with an example of the syntax for these kind of triggers ?